Weigela branches become hollow and break off easily by hand
My weigela shrub has large holes in the branches near the ground. The branches eventually die and can be broken off easily because they are hollow inside. These ones are the larger branches.
Appears something is eating holes in the branches from the inside of the branch. A 4 to 5 inch circumference branch can be easily broken off near the ground by hand.

Hi Annie, welcome to the site.  Could we get a picture or two?

Prune more. Old limbs dying is pretty normal for weglia, so if you cut out everything over about 3 years old and let the plant make new branches the overall health of it improves.

Assuming that your Weigela is suffering a boring insect infestation, i would begin damage control by first pruning off any infested branches and then incinerating them to prevent the insects from reinfesting the bush, then applying a systemic insecticide like Malathion to kill any you didn't find or have newly arrived. I would then attempt to look for any nearby shrubs or trees that may be harbouring the bugs and treating them in the same way, as these things can't have materialized out of thin air...
